# Error validating archive from iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I have tried on Xcode 7.2 & 7.3, archive validation fails with a very generic error.

[image]

It did not give me any error while archiving.

Can anyone please point me in correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some error with Image assets I was using, which the Organizer does not point out.
Using Application Builder solved the problem for me, as it specifes the issue with the IPA.